# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{6n^4+n^3+3}{2n^4-n+1}=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

How to prove, using the definition of limit of a sequence, that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{6n^4+n^3+3}{2n^4-n+1}=3$$

Subtracting 3 and taking the absolute value of the function I have:

$$<\frac{n^3+3n}{2n^4-n}$$

But it's hard to get forward...

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $n^4$ in the original expression, then let $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Like minds think alike?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  think so: only their internet speeds may differ.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Well, I mean I had to type out the fractions and what-not.  But according to the first line "definition of limit of a sequence", we are probably supposed to use $\epsilon$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then you have to use a bunch of inequalities to simplify things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{6n^4+n^3+3}{2n^4-n+1}-3\right|<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow \left|\frac{n^3+3n}{2n^4-n+1}\right|<\epsilon.$$ Now, $4n^3\ge n^3+3n$ and $2n^4-n+1\ge n^4$ for all $n$ positive integer. So $$\left|\frac{n^3+3n}{2n^4-n+1}\right|\le \frac{4n^3}{n^4}=\frac{4}{n},$$ and choosing $n_0=\lfloor 4/\epsilon \rfloor+1$  we have $\dfrac{4}{n}<\epsilon$ if $n\ge n_0,$ as a consequence $$\left|\frac{6n^4+n^3+3}{2n^4-n+1}-3\right|<\epsilon\text{ if }n\ge \left\lfloor \frac{4}{\epsilon} \right\rfloor+1.$$

Answer (score 4):

> Subtracting 3 and taking the absolute value of the function I have:
>
> $$<\frac{n^3+3n}{2n^4-n}$$

Then, since $n^2 \gt 3$ and $2n^3-1 \gt n^3$ for $n \gt 1\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{n^3+3n}{2n^4-n} = \frac{\cancel{n}(n^2+3)}{\cancel{n}(2n^3-1)} \lt \frac{n^2+n^2}{n^3} = \frac{2}{n}
$$

You should hopefully be able to take it from there.

Comment: Lol, as I am definitely too lazy at this hour in the day (US time)

Comment: @dxiv wow, is it that simple? Does that complete the answer or do you have to use the epsilon to show n>1/2e?

Comment: @Tony XD Well, you have to see it first.  Then it's simple

Comment: @Tony If you know (or can otherwise use) the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) [for sequences](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135350/how-to-prove-the-squeeze-theorem-for-sequences) then you are essentially done. If you do need to write the full epsilon-delta prrof, then at least you have an easy to estimate $1 / 2n$ upper bound.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Math is where laziness is often an asset  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$. If $n\geq N$, then we get
$$\begin{align}\left|\frac{6n^4+n^3+3}{2n^4-n+1}-3 \right|&
=\left|\frac{n^3+3n}{2n^4-n+1}\right|\\&=\frac{n^3+3n}{2n^4-n+1}\\
&<\frac{n^3+3n}{2n^4-n}\\
&\leq\frac{n^3+3n}{2n^4-n^4}\\
&\leq\frac{n^3+3n^3}{n^4}\\
&=\frac{4}{n}\leq\frac{4}{N}<\epsilon.
\end{align}$$
Hope it helps.