# Sequences convergence property

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be two real-valued sequences. Suppose that $a_n\leq b_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}b_n = 0.$$

I would like to know: it is true that also $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n = 0$?

Why?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: show your efforts. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: $a_n$ must be non-negative, unless we can have counterexamples like $$b_n={1\over n}$$ and $$a_n=-1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if we can take $a_n$ to be negative. Suppose $b_n =0, a_n = -1$ for all $n$. Then $a_n \leq b_n, \lim_n b_n = 0,\lim_n a_n = -1 \neq 0$. If $0 \leq a_n \leq b_n$, then yes, as a consequence of the [Squeeze Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135350/how-to-prove-the-squeeze-theorem-for-sequences).