# Help/hint for proving the squeeze theorem in calculus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-explanation

I wondered if I could get some starting help with an assignment, which is proving the squeeze theorem. The assignment is as followed:

Show that if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}b_n = A$ and $a_n \leq c_n \leq b_n$ for all $n$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}c_n = A$.

I know that I could just google the full proof, but it's a learning process so I wondered if I could get a hint... because I just don't know where to start with this one. It's for a calculus-course.

Comment: Hint: What does $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}c_n = A$ mean mathematically? (unpack the definition) Can you use what you know about the $a_n$'s and $b_n$'s to show that?

Comment: +1 for your attitude

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135350/how-to-prove-the-squeeze-theorem-for-sequences). The top answers happen to be a hint.

Answer (score 1):

**Definition**. One says that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=A$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N>0$ such that $$n>N\Rightarrow |a_n-A|<\epsilon.$$ Note that geometrically, $$|a_n-A|<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow a_n\in (A-\epsilon,A+\epsilon),$$ and $$|b_n-A|<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow b_n\in (A-\epsilon,A+\epsilon).$$

If both $a_n$ and $b_n$ lie in the same interval $(A-\epsilon,A+\epsilon)$ and $a_n\leq c_n\leq b_n$, what can you say about $c_n$?

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that since $|a_n-A| < \epsilon$, $|b_n-A| < \epsilon$ and $a_n \leq c_n \leq b_n$ then $|c_n-A| < \epsilon$. How can I formalize this to a proof?

Comment: Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_1$ such that $n>N_1\Rightarrow |a_n-A|<\epsilon.$ Similarly, there exists $N_2$ such that $n>N_2\Rightarrow |b_n-A|<\epsilon.$ Now take $N=\max(N_1,N_2).$ What can you conclude? (Compare the proof of kobe along this line in the link given in one of the comments.)

Comment: Since $c_n \geq a_n$ then $c_n-A \geq a_n-A > -\epsilon$, and since $c_n \leq b_n$ then $c_n-A \leq b_n-A < \epsilon$. If $N = \max(N_1, N_2)$, then $-\epsilon < c_n-A < \epsilon$...